# How to remove subclass of UILabel in itself

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

A subclass of `UILabel` called `NewLabel`, in `NewLabel.m`

```
+ (NewLabel*)addLabelIntoView:(UIView*)view
{
  NewLabel *label = [[NewLabel alloc] init];
  CGSize size = CGSizeMake(120.0f, 40.0f);
  CGPoint point = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width / 2, view.bounds.size.height / 2);
  label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
  label.center = point;
  [view addSubview:label];
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(removeLabelFromView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
  return label;
}

- (void)removeLabelFromView {
 [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

and in a `UIViewController.m`, I add this for showing the NewLabel, and close itself

```
[NewLabel addLabelIntoView:self.view]
```

but it always crash, here is crash info

```
+[NewLabel removeLabelFromView]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x103d40738
```

Any ideas?

Comment: where you written this code `- (void)removeLabelFromView { [self removeFromSuperview]; }` in viewController or other ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha I write them in subclass of UILabel, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a class method is `self` the class. Instead of `+[NewLabel removeLabelFromView]` you probably want to do `-[NewLabel removeLabelFromView]`. Change

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(removeLabelFromView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

to

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:label selector:@selector(removeLabelFromView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```